# How to show certain datafields in a DataGrid based on another field?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

I have a form were the user can fill in 3 different costs then click on a tick box and approve one of the costs. The cost that is approved then needs to be displayed on the `DataGrid`

Code for DataGrid:

```
<asp:DataGrid CssClass="tblResults" runat="server" ID="dgDetails" OnItemDataBound="dgDetails_ItemDataBound" DataKeyField="ID" AutoGenerateColumns="false" style="display:none">
<HeaderStyle CssClass="tblResultsHeader" />
<AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="#EEEEEE" />
 <Columns>                                       
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Code" HeaderText="Code"></asp:BoundColumn>
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Cost" HeaderText="Cost"> </asp:BoundColumn>
         <asp:HyperLinkColumn DataNavigateUrlFormatString="javascript:deleteDetail({0})" DataNavigateUrlField="ID" HeaderText="Delete" DataTextField="ID" ItemStyle-CssClass="tblRowDelete" ></asp:HyperLinkColumn>                                       
  </Columns>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void dgDetails_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.Header && e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.Footer && e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.Pager)
    {
        Quote.QuoteDetails qd = (Quote.QuoteDetails)e.Item.DataItem;

        e.Item.Attributes.Add("ID", "dgDetails_" + qd.ID);
        e.Item.Attributes.Add("class", "dgDetailsRow");
        e.Item.ToolTip = "Click here to Edit Detail";
}
```

The problem is displaying the correct cost in the `DataGrid`. Right now it is displaying the DataField `Cost`. But if the second `Cost` has been approved then I needs to display the DataField `Cost2`. Is there a way to have an if statement in the `DataGrid` to check which cost has been approved? Something like:

```
if(approved1.checked)
{
   <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Cost" HeaderText="Cost"> </asp:BoundColumn>
}
else if (approved2.checked)
{
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Cost2" HeaderText="Cost"> </asp:BoundColumn>
}
```

Can if statements be added in the `DataGrid`? Or is there a way to do this from the code behind?

Comment: Where are `Checkboxes` present

Comment: @DheerajPatnaik the checkboxes are in the same form as the costs. They are saved in the same table in the database

Comment: I meant to ask, is it present in the `gridview` columns or outside the `gridview`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use code behind and a template column.

```
<asp:TemplateColumn>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblCost" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

With code behind similar to:

```
protected void dg1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
{
    Label lblCost;
    Quote.QuoteDetails qd = (Quote.QuoteDetails)e.Item.DataItem;

    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        lblCost = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblCost");

        if (qd.Approved1)
            lblCost.Text = string.Format("{0:0.00", qd.Cost);
        else if (qd.Approved2)
            lblCost.Text = string.Format("{0:0.00", qd.Cost2);
        else
            throw new NotImplementedException("oops!");
    }
}
```